# Set up version control integration with PHP Storm?

Tags: mamp, phpstorm

In PHP Storm if I go "View" / "Tool Windows" then "Version Control" is greyed out and unclickable. Im trying to set this up.

I think this is the documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/associating-a-project-root-with-a-version-control-system.html

"Select VCS | Enable Version Control Integration from the main menu, or press ^ V, and select Enable Version Control Integration."

I have the "VCS" menu but no option of "Enable Version Control Integration". Are these instructions for PC and is it different for Mac?

Comment: Do you have the trial version or the licensed one?

Comment: I have a licensed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For active `Version Control` item in `View | Tool Windows` you need registry current project in settings.

Go to `Preferences...` <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> then select `Version Control`:

[image]

Here add <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> configuration of current project. After that verify whether `Version Control` item is activated.